# vc-diff of git-based file in emacs shows two versions of the file, rather than just diffs

Tags: git, emacs

If I run `vc-diff` when in an edited file of a git repro, I git a new buffer that shows me way more than I expected. It marks every line of the HEAD version of the file as deleted, and every line of the working copy of the file as added, so basically I see two full versions of the file.

This is not very useful!

If I run `git diff path\to\edited\file` in dos, or in git bash, I get what I expect vc-diff to give me: a short diff with just the actually added and deleted lines.

I have magit installed and when I look at diffs in that I get the same problem.

This is on windows running the official windows binary of emacs 24.1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would bet solid money you've changed your line endings accidentally in your editor, or have a `core.autocrlf` setting that's changed them for you. In other words, it's showing a diff because in one version, the lines end in CRLF; in the other, they end in just LF.

I'd poke at your editor settings and see what `git config --global core.autocrlf` returns.

Comment: I think you're right. It seems magit and vc-git are ignoring all my git config settings - when I commit magit gives me a nonsense email address instead of either the --global one I have set up or the one local to the current repro. Looks like I need to ask a different question.

Comment: @tenpn Yeah afraid I can't help you there as I don't know `vc-diff` at all, but that'd definitely do it.

Comment: Asked here why emacs is ignoring my git config: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424470/why-is-vc-git-and-magit-in-emacs-ignoring-my-git-config-settings