# why is vc-git and magit in emacs ignoring my git config settings?

Tags: windows, git, emacs, magit

I'm running the official windows binary of emacs 24.1.1 with magit. When I commit a file, the username and email shown on the log are ripped from my account and machine name, rather than using the values set in either the global git config or the local settings for this repro.

From git bash and dos, I can ask git for user.email and user.name and get the local repro settings.

magit and vc-git's diff mode also seems to be ignoring my autocrlf settings, so this may be an emacs-wide problem, not specific to magit.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd` is is on emac's `exec-path`.

How can I either instruct magit to find the correct settings, or tell it manually what the settings are?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might want to control that your $HOME is the same from Emacs point of view, and from your shell point of view. Chances are that they're not the same, hence $HOME/.gitconfig is not found in Emacs.

Comment: Yep - emacs was looking at c:\users\me\AppData\Roaming\ when both dos and git bash were looking at c:\users\me\. This page http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows-HOME.html describes how HOME works for emacs on windows, and how to change it.

Answer (score 1):

you can add a HOME enviroment varibales and specify the dir the same with the .gitconfig dir.